# $i = i \implies -1 = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

Here's a little bit of a strange question: In class, my math teacher decided to let us take a break from the usual class to solve a mathematical puzzle:

\begin{align}
i & = i \\
i^2 &= i^2 \\
\sqrt{-1} &= \sqrt{-1} \\
\sqrt{\frac{-1}{1}} &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}} \\
\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{1}} &= \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}} \\
i &= \frac{1}{i}
\end{align}

I assume that the transition from line 4 to 5 is wrong, but I don't see how :p.

Does anyone care to explain?

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has two square roots.

Comment: This exact thing has been posted before.  See the link above/below.  If that specific post is not identical enough of a duplicate for you, consider going through the other linked questions/answers attached to that post.  The short explanation is that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\neq \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ in general unless $a$ and $b$ are both positive.

Answer (score 0):

The function $t \mapsto \sqrt{t}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. You can extend this notion to the whole real line (actually, to $\mathbb{C}$), but you lose some properties. Particularly, you lose the product rule you're using to "prove" the statement (the fourth equality to be precise).